# How to figure out which GLSL (ESSL) version Qt uses on my PC?

Tags: qt, opengl-es, qml, glsl

I'm using *ESSL* (OpenGL ES Shading language) via Canvas3D in Qt. On my machine I run Windows and have set the following:

```
QGuiApplication::setAttribute(Qt::AA_UseOpenGLES);
```

in `main()`, which means that GL calls get translated by Qt to GL ES calls, which get translated by ANGLE to Direct3D calls. At least I believe that's what it means. I'm using the following test QML code to see what OpenGL version is used:

```
Text {
    text: OpenGLInfo.majorVersion + "." + OpenGLInfo.minorVersion
}
```

This displays "2.0". I'm not sure if that's the GL API version or the GL ES API version. Also I'm not sure which ESSL version this GL/GLES version maps to. I found a table mapping the versions [here](https://github.com/mattdesl/lwjgl-basics/wiki/GLSL-Versions) but that's not a reliable enough source for me. Also unlike the ESSL docs it lists ESSL versions in a decimal-point-free format, e.g. version "330" rather than "3.3", and it lacks e.g. version 3.00 (aka 300) which [the ESSL docs](https://www.khronos.org/opengles/sdk/docs/man31/html/textureSize.xhtml) mention.

So the question is:
**How to figure out which ESSL version Qt uses on my PC?**

## Side note - what prompted my question:

I want to use the `textureSize` ESSL function, but I'm getting the following error:

```
ERROR: 0:4: 'textureSize' : no matching overloaded function found 
ERROR: 0:4: '=' :  cannot convert from 'const float' to 'highp 2-component vector of int'
```

My test shader looks like this:

```
uniform sampler2D uSampler;

void main(void) {
    highp ivec2 texSize = textureSize(uSampler, 0);
    gl_FragColor = vec4(0.0);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I found a roundabout way to do it. Did the following in the shader:

```
if(__VERSION__  > 150) {
    gl_FragColor = vec4(1.0, 0.0. 0.0, 1.0);
}
```

And play with the number 150 to find when it draws red and when not.

That way's not great though.

Answer (score 0):

I found a better way:

```
gl.getString(gl.SHADING_LANGUAGE_VERSION);
```

However, it doesn't seem to work in Canvas3D. See this [post of mine](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40384885/qt-canvas3d-gl-getstring-fails).