# Why can't I use OpenGL ES 3.0 in Qt?

Tags: qt, opengl-es, opengl-es-3.0

I set a `QSurfaceFormat` on my window, and this surface format has "3.0" set as its GL version number. The code:

```
static QSurfaceFormat createSurfaceFormat() {
    QSurfaceFormat format;
    format.setSamples(4);
    format.setDepthBufferSize(24);
    format.setStencilBufferSize(8);
    format.setVersion(3, 0);
    return format;
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    // ...

    QQmlApplicationEngine engine;
    engine.load(QUrl(QStringLiteral("qrc:/main.qml")));
    QWindow* window = (QWindow*) engine.rootObjects().first();
    window->setFormat(::createSurfaceFormat());

    // ...
}
```

Also, in `main()` I enable OpenGL ES mode, like this:

```
QGuiApplication::setAttribute(Qt::AA_UseOpenGLES);
```

This means I'm requesting a GL ES 3.0 context.

The [ANGLE docs](https://github.com/google/angle) say (in a table near the beginning) that `GL ES 3.0 -> D3D 11` API translation support is implemented. And my system supports D3D 11 according to `dxdiag.exe`.

But when I launch my app, which contains this QML code...

```
Text {
    text: OpenGLInfo.majorVersion + "." + OpenGLInfo.minorVersion
}
```

... I see "2.0" is displayed. Also, using the method I described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40382590), I've determined that the maximal supported shading language version on my PC is "100" aka 1.0.

At the same time, from [this Qt blog post](http://blog.qt.io/blog/2015/09/09/cross-platform-opengl-es-3-apps-with-qt-5-6/) I know that Qt supports GL ES 3.0 apps.

So **why can't I use OpenGL ES 3.0 in Qt**?

Comment: *I set a QSurfaceFormat on my window, and this surface format has "3.0" set as its GL version number* how do you do that exactly? What window class are you talking about?

Comment: @peppe: I edited the question to include that information.

Comment: The way pasted in the code looks wrong, as it's setting the format *after* the creation of the window (and that's too late, you must set it before). Try caling `QSurfaceFormat::setDefaultFormat` before you create your `Q(Gui)Application` object in main.

Comment: @peppe: Thanks, this worked. Would you please post it as an answer, so I can mark it accepted?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to set a QSurfaceFormat on a QWindow before the window itself is created (via `create()`). If you create top level windows via QML you have no control on when `create()` gets actually called, so a solution is changing the default surface format somwhere before you create your Q(Gui)Application:

```
int main(int argc, char **argv) {
    // createSurfaceFormat() is the function you pasted above
    QSurfaceFormat::setDefaultFormat(createSurfaceFormat());

    QApplication app(argc, argv); 
    // etc.
```